# Should horribly wrong answers be deleted?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003531/352552), which is about to be deleted, and the one below it  (non 10K below).

The former showed up in the 10K queue, flagged as "low quality".  Should either this answer, or the one below it qualify as such?

They seem like real answers to me, just horribly, horribly wrong.  Shouldn't they just be left to be down-voted?

Aren't mods here to be `janitors who clean up puke, not professors who make sure your assignments are correct`?

[image]

Comment: And if any mod notices, yes, I cast a delete vote for the first one.  I saw the -8 votes, and grayed out text, so I reached for the delete button before reading.  Yes, I'm human :)

Comment: Odd that nobody took the time to explain to him that he is fundamentally incorrect.  I assume it would be obvious by the other answers...

Comment: @Won't also obvious by all the downvotes :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. That's why high rep users can vote to delete. That is also why there is a peer pressure badge, to encourage users to delete *their own* downvoted content.

We want to identify harmful answers, but we do not necessarily want them to stick around. Even though their scores are negative, even though the content might be grayed out, people can still see them, ignore the warnings (or not even understand them) and *use the content.*

Delete the content and save the world the trouble. The correct answers are still visible to provide that guiding light, we don't need the wrong answers to also be visible in order to ward off evil.

Comment: Ok - I agree.  That makes sense to me