# Why are we happy to delete open questions with 0 score but not terrible, incorrect answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I’ve come across some really bad answers on Stack Exchange, including quite a few that are just one sentence with no sources or badly written speculation with no basis. From what I understand, our policy is to basically never delete answers due to terrible quality as long as they attempt to answer the question. However, we delete open 0 or less scoring questions after 365 days with very little activity and views. Why do we do this? What makes it so that questions that nobody paid attention to but don’t have a negative score should be deleted but really, really bad answers shouldn’t?

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, a wrong answer (which is clearly indicated as being wrong by having a negative score; answers scoring -3 or lower are grayed out) still provides instructional value; it indicates what people **should not do** when they have the same question as the OP. This may be very helpful if for whatever reason they can't use the advice given in a good scoring answer, or if such an answer isn't present *at all* on the current question. Also, it saves time for users who think they have a brilliant solution to a certain question, but in fact fall for the same trap as the author of the bad/wrong answer.

Note that some sites in the network might still delete (blatantly) wrong answers instead of just downvoting them, see [Can we clarify the 'Delete an answer' criteria?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307641/295232). That is however done by users themselves (and happens rather soon after they've been posted), not by Roomba. Also, bad posts are bound to attract Very Low Quality flags, and the Low Quality Posts review queue will *delete* answers (if the reviewers choose to do so) but only *close* questions.

A final thought: the Roomba process is identical for all sites. There are many questions on Stack Overflow having received little or no attention which should have been closed because they're unclear or too broad, but simply weren't because they haven't been properly tagged and/or the Close Vote review queue is too full to take care of them. You might be more experienced with (slightly) smaller sites, where that simply doesn't happen that often.

Comment: One advantage of leaving a clearly incorrect answer that has down votes is to discourage others from posting the same misinformation. For example, [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53953/8499) was left for that exact reason.

Answer (score 4):

> From what I understand, our policy is to basically never deleted answers due to terrible quality as long as they attempt to answer the question.

This is not true. We delete link-only answers, we delete duplicate answers, we delete incorrect answers, we delete answers that are irrelevant to the question asked, etc. An answer does need to be a bit more than an attempt to answer the question to remain undeleted.

> However, we delete open 0 or less score questions after 365 days with very little activity and views. Why do we do this?

If a question gets no upvotes, no answers, and very few views and comments after a *year*, then, well... it's *probably* not that great of a question if barely anybody's even bothered to *look* at it, and nobody who did look at it considered it worth an upvote or an answer.

Now, there's also the problem of high-scoring but outdated or incorrect answers. Solutions [have been proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314172/implement-a-way-to-deprecate-answers) in various places and IMHO seriously needs to be addressed.

Comment: Well on sci-if we keep completely factually inaccurate stuff like [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/33483/102999), which is definitely incorrect (see comments)

Comment: @Stormblessed I didn't really mean factually incorrect answers; as your example shows, they tend to get heavily downvoted and *sometimes*, but not always, deleted. Hopefully the edit made it a little better.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, the reason why we don't delete answers for being "incorrect" is rather straightforward. It is very difficult to objectively qualify an answer as incorrect. This is especially true on many of the sites on the network which deal with topics that are not really subject to empirical testing.

So who gets to decide when an answer is incorrect? Is an answer incorrect because a high reputation user said so? Surely high reputation users can be wrong. Is an answer incorrect when it gets a lot of downvotes? Surely a majority opinion doesn't make something correct. Given that for the most part we can't objectively declare answers to be incorrect, we don't delete them. Instead we have downvotes and comments where it can be shown that a large part of the community think that the answer is incorrect.

The reason why questions are deleted is not that they are incorrect. As explained in [the Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) documenting the introduction of the features to automatically delete certain questions, the primary reason for removing them is that they clutter up search results without providing useful content. Even if an incorrect answer turns up in a search results, there is likely still useful content on the page in the question and other answers. When a question has no answers to begin with there won't really be useful content on the page. Furthermore, in light of the preceding paragraphs about how we can't objectively determine that an answer is incorrect, it is even possible that what you consider to be an incorrect answer may actually itself be useful to other readers.